# Custom input type=date in jquery mobile 1.2.1

Tags: jquery-mobile

I use input type "date" with jquery mobile. But for each device it display different result. 
+ Android operating system: choose input date the same type of android calendar
+ iOS: choose input date date the sam type of iOS
+ Desktop: choose input date the same type of operating system install on desktop

I want display dd/MM/yyyy format standard for all device. How to custom format default input date???

Thank you so much!

Comment: Check here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106970/jquery-mobile-ui-datepicker-change-date-format>

Comment: Check out Mobiscroll http://demo.mobiscroll.com/datetime/date#

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but this is too much of a waste of time and involves cumbersome use of HTML5's `localStorage` api. For more info, look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format). In this case also, it's not possible to make `type=date` behave uniformly in all browsers because **each** browser handles this differently and you don't have any control over it.

HTML5's standards indicate usage of `YYYY-MM-DD` format but the browsers sniff your local date format and use that. See this from [w3](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/forms.html#input-author-notes):

> The format used "on the wire", i.e. in HTML markup and in form submissions, is intended to be computer-readable and consistent irrespective of the user's locale. Dates, for instance, are always written in the format "YYYY-MM-DD", as in "2003-02-01". Users are not expected to ever see this format.

and [this question](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/demos/faq/my-html-5-inputs-look-different-in-browsers.php) at jquery Mobile site.

All this must tell you that doing this will take a lot of effort from you. Instead, it would be better if you use some other alternative to this, taken from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320600/jquery-mobile-date-picker) like this : http://jsbin.com/ukelis/1/edit

you could change the dateformat in the `altFormat` option in the JS and make this work for you. You could also look at [this](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/source/browse/trunk/com.mds.apg/resources/jqm/demo2/experiments/ui-datepicker/jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js?r=92) - a mobile version for jquery UI's datepicker.

Comment: please be sure to mark this as the best answer if you feel this has helped you and upvote it if u think this will help others. :)